# Dwell clicking software that supports right-dragging and allows to define shortcuts

Tags: software-recommendation, mouse, accessibility, click

I am looking for a dwell clicking software that supports as many following features as possible:

- left and right-dragging
- double/triple click
- a shortcut can be defined to change the mouse mode
- the mouse mode window is always on Top
- customizable dwell clicking time (i.e. the time one needs to hold the mouse steady in an area before the mouse click is sent)

---

A few definitions:

- Right-dragging = you click the right mouse button while pointing at something, hold down the right mouse button and drag the object somewhere
- [Dwell clicking](http://www.bltt.org/quicktips/mouse_dwell.htm) = Instead of having to press a mouse button or a switch the user needs to simply hold the mouse steady in an area for a predefined amount of time. This action issues the computer with a 'virtual' click and provides the same function as if someone had pressed the mouse button.

---

On Windows I use [Point-N-Click](http://www.polital.com/pnc/) dwell clicking software: it has all the above-mentioned features (and is free).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DwellClick](http://pilotmoon.com/dwellclick/) is a nice dwell clicking app on mac that is customizable, versatile, as well as nice-looking. The following pictures show the hands-free panel and the pop-up panel of the app.

[image: Hands free panel]
[image: Pop-up panel]

It supports most of the features you mentioned:

- single/double click, drag, drag & hold
- keyboard shortcuts for changing modes
- hands-free panel that stays on top
- customizable dwell clicking time

In addition, there are other features such as:

- modified click with ⇧, ⌃, ⌥ or ⌘
- pop-up panel near the mouse pointer to select different modes

The only modes missing from your inquiry are triple click and right drag, but I don't think Mac OS uses these modes. However, it should be easy to configure a desired short cut or action to the modified clicks using [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/what-is-bettertouchtool/) mentioned above, so that you can use them instead.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen anything on Dwell for mac unfortunately. I've started playing with [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/what-is-bettertouchtool/) since Jitouch hasn't updated for Yosemite. BTT seems more versatile if not as nicely predefined. BTT enables assigning actions to trackpad gestures or mouse. I don't know how to integrate dwell clicking, sounds interesting.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, BTT is great indeed but I'm afraid it does not have any dwell clicking function indeed :(